# Selecting HTML nodes

Tags: html, clojure, lisp

I'm new to Clojure, and I'm writing some code that processes HTML. I'm parsing the HTML using clj-tagsoup and then trying to pull out the relevant bits with this function:

```
(defn find-nodes [tag-prototype base-node]
  (letfn [(node-matches [tag-prototype node]
            (let [[tag attrs] tag-prototype]
              (and (= (nth node 0) tag)
                   (every? (fn [[key val]]
                             (= (key (nth node 1)) val))
                           (seq attrs)))))]
    (if (node-matches tag-prototype base-node)
      [base-node]
      (loop [nodes base-node matches []]
        (if (seq nodes)
          (recur (next nodes)
                 (let [node (first nodes)]
                   (if (vector? node)
                     (if (node-matches tag-prototype node)
                       (conj matches node)
                       (concat matches (find-nodes tag-prototype node)))
                     matches)))
          matches)))))
```

Used something like this:

```
(->> (tagsoup/parse file)
     (find-nodes [:div {:class "magic"}])
     (find-nodes [:p]))
```

The code works (finally), but the style is probably horrible. What would you suggest to improve it?

Sample input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="something-important">
      <p class="alert">
        ...
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="something-else">
      <p class="message">
        Hello World.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample query:

```
(pprint (find-nodes [:div {:id "something-important"}]
                    (tagsoup/parse "test.html")))
```

Sample output:

```
([:div
  {:id "something-important"}
  [:p {:class "alert"} "\n        ...\n      "]])
```

Sample query:

```
(pprint (find-nodes [:p]
                    (tagsoup/parse "test.html")))
```

Sample output:

```
([:p {:class "alert"} "\n        ...\n      "]
 [:p {:class "message"} "\n        Hello World.\n      "])
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Comment: You may wish to review Enlive:  https://github.com/cgrand/enlive

Answer (score 3):

First things first: any time you find yourself using `letfn`, you should strongly consider simply breaking those functions out into their own `defn`s. In this case, `node-matches` is large enough and decoupled enough to make that clearly the right choice.

One way you can make your code more concise is to take advantage of the fact that you can do destructuring directly in function arguments:

```clj
(defn node-matches [[tag attrs] [node-tag node-attrs]]
  (and (= node-tag tag)
       (every? (fn [[key val]]
                 (= (key node-attrs) val))
               (seq attrs))))
```

If you want to make clear what it is that you're destructuring, you could add `:as prototype` and `:as node` to your parameters.

When you think about it, though, that `every?` expression is really just trying to determine if `attrs` is a subset of `node-attrs`. In Clojure, you can use the [`subset?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/subset_q) function to do that. So, assuming that you've already required `[clojure.set :as set]`:

```clj
(set/subset? (set attrs) (set node-attrs))
```

A lot of the complexity in the rest of `find-nodes` comes from the fact that you're complecting the logic that traverses the HTML tree and the logic that uses `node-matches` to do the matching and assemble the final result.

The best way to improve `find-nodes`, then, is to break it apart. Actually, traversing a Hiccup-style HTML tree is incredibly easy in Clojure using the [`tree-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq) function:

```clj
(tree-seq vector? tagsoup/children (tagsoup/parse "test.html"))
```

This will give you a sequence of all the nodes in the HTML tree:

```clj
([:html {}
  [:head {}
   [:title {} "This is a test page"]]
  [:body {}
   [:div {:id "something-important"}
    [:p {:class "alert"}
     "\n        ...\n      "]]
   [:div {:id "something-else"}
    [:p {:class "message"}
     "\n        Hello World.\n      "]]]]
 [:head {}
  [:title {} "This is a test page"]]
 [:title {} "This is a test page"]
 "This is a test page"
 [:body {}
  [:div {:id "something-important"}
   [:p {:class "alert"}
    "\n        ...\n      "]]
  [:div {:id "something-else"}
   [:p {:class "message"}
    "\n        Hello World.\n      "]]]
 [:div {:id "something-important"}
  [:p {:class "alert"}
   "\n        ...\n      "]]
 [:p {:class "alert"}
  "\n        ...\n      "]
 "\n        ...\n      "
 [:div {:id "something-else"}
  [:p {:class "message"}
   "\n        Hello World.\n      "]]
 [:p {:class "message"}
  "\n        Hello World.\n      "]
 "\n        Hello World.\n      ")
```

And at this point, you're pretty much done. You just need to [`filter`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) this sequence using the shortened version of `node-matches` that we wrote above:

```clj
(defn find-nodes [[tag attrs] root]
  (filter (fn [[node-tag node-attrs]]
            (and (= tag node-tag) (set/subset? (set attrs) (set node-attrs))))
          (tree-seq vector? tagsoup/children root)))
```